# How do you delete rows with values that appear in multiple rows and columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with quite a few columns and rows, many of which repeat. I would like to get ride of any rows containing specific values: Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4 and Playdoh_Butterfly_Unnatural.mp4. They both appear at least 7 times in the columns filename_right and filename_left. However whenever I try to remove those values, it does not work. I have tried several methods

```
import <- read.csv("rawData/session_1_anon.csv", na.strings = Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4 & Playdoh_Butterfly_Unnatural.mp4)
```

which returns

```
object 'Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4' not found
```

```
import[!(row.names(import) %in% c('Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4','Playdoh_Butterfly_Unnatural.mp4')), ]


import[!(import$filename_left=="Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4" & 
import$filename_right=="Playdoh_Butterfly_Unnatural.mp4"),]


import <- subset(import, filename_left != "Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4", filename_right != "Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4")
```

I have also tried the three lines above. None of them return an error, but they also don't remove the values. I'm feeling very stuck and don't know how else to remove these values/rows. Can anyone help? Thank you!

```
   Block_Nr Block_Name Task_Nr             Task_Name Trial_Nr Trial_Id ATT_CHECK_1 ATT_CHECK_2 ATT_CHECK_3
1         1    block_1      10            end_of_exp        1        1                                    
2         1    block_1       9       Attention_check        1        3                ANI_left            
3         1    block_1       9       Attention_check        2        7                                    
4         1    block_1       9       Attention_check        3        5                            ANI_left
5         1    block_1       9       Attention_check        4        1    ANI_left                        
6         1    block_1       8          Take_a_break        1        1                                    
7         1    block_1       7 Standard_Video_Trials        1       10                                    
8         1    block_1       7 Standard_Video_Trials        2       33                                    
9         1    block_1       7 Standard_Video_Trials        3       14                                    
10        1    block_1       7 Standard_Video_Trials        4       31                                    
11        1    block_1       7 Standard_Video_Trials        5       24                                    
12        1    block_1       7 Standard_Video_Trials        6       16                                    
13        1    block_1       7 Standard_Video_Trials        7       25                                    
14        1    block_1       7 Standard_Video_Trials        8       17                                    
15        1    block_1       7 Standard_Video_Trials        9        4                                    
   ATT_CHECK_4 Condition_Id datenschutz deleted_var_ deleted_var__80a0e
1                         1                       NA                 NA
2                         1                       NA                 NA
3     ANI_left            1                       NA                 NA
4                         1                       NA                 NA
5                         1                       NA                 NA
6                         1                       NA                 NA
7                         2                       NA                 NA
8                         1                       NA                 NA
9                         2                       NA                 NA
10                        1                       NA                 NA
11                        2                       NA                 NA
12                        2                       NA                 NA
13                        1                       NA                 NA
14                        1                       NA                 NA
15                        2                       NA                 NA
   deleted_var_copy_of_copy_of_copy_of_SMI_1_side deleted_var_copy_of_copy_of_SMI_1_side
1                                              NA                                     NA
2                                              NA                                     NA
3                                              NA                                     NA
4                                              NA                                     NA
5                                              NA                                     NA
6                                              NA                                     NA
7                                              NA                                     NA
8                                              NA                                     NA
9                                              NA                                     NA
10                                             NA                                     NA
11                                             NA                                     NA
12                                             NA                                     NA
13                                             NA                                     NA
14                                             NA                                     NA
15                                             NA                                     NA
   deleted_var_copy_of_SMI_1_side deleted_var_SMI_1_side deleted_var_SMI_3 Drawing_Boat_01 Drawing_Car_01
1                              NA                     NA                NA                               
2                              NA                     NA                NA                               
3                              NA                     NA                NA                               
4                              NA                     NA                NA                               
5                              NA                     NA                NA                               
6                              NA                     NA                NA                               
7                              NA                     NA                NA                               
8                              NA                     NA                NA                               
9                              NA                     NA                NA                               
10                             NA                     NA                NA                               
11                             NA                     NA                NA                               
12                             NA                     NA                NA                               
13                             NA                     NA                NA                               
14                             NA                     NA                NA                               
15                             NA                     NA                NA       NAT_right               
   Drawing_Crown_01 Drawing_Dog_01 Drawing_Donkey_01 Drawing_Flower_01 Drawing_House_01 Drawing_PalmTree_01
1                                                                                                          
2                                                                                                          
3                                                                                                          
4                                                                                                          
5                                                                                                          
6                                                                                                          
7                        NAT_right                                                                         
8                                                                                                          
9                                                            NAT_right                                     
10                                                                                                         
11                                                                                                         
12                                                                            NAT_right                    
13                                                                                                         
14                                                                                                 NAT_left
15                                                                                                         
   Drawing_Tree_02 einverstanden ELE_1 ELE_2 ELE_3 ELE_4 factor1_tg1_task3                   filename_left
1                                   NA    NA    NA    NA                NA                                
2                                   NA    NA    NA    NA                NA                       2-cat.mp4
3                                   NA    NA    NA    NA                NA                  4-hedgehog.mp4
4                                   NA    NA    NA    NA                NA                      3-hare.mp4
5                                   NA    NA    NA    NA                NA                       1-dog.mp4
6                                   NA    NA    NA    NA                NA                                
7                                   NA    NA    NA    NA                NA       Drawing_Dog_Unnatural.mp4
8                                   NA    NA    NA    NA                NA       Playdoh_Winky_Natural.mp4
9                                   NA    NA    NA    NA                NA    Drawing_Flower_Unnatural.mp4
10                                  NA    NA    NA    NA                NA      Playdoh_Turtle_Natural.mp4
11                                  NA    NA    NA    NA                NA Playdoh_Butterfly_Unnatural.mp4
12                                  NA    NA    NA    NA                NA     Drawing_House_Unnatural.mp4
13                                  NA    NA    NA    NA                NA      Playdoh_Flower_Natural.mp4
14                                  NA    NA    NA    NA                NA    Drawing_PalmTree_Natural.mp4
15                                  NA    NA    NA    NA                NA      Drawing_Boat_Unnatural.mp4
                   filename_right KEB_1 KEB_2 KEB_3 KEB_4 key_press Origami_Airplane_01 Origami_Heart_01
1                                    NA    NA    NA    NA                                               
2                     2-grass.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         A                                     
3                  4-building.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         A                                     
4                     3-daisy.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         A                                     
5                      1-rose.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         A                                     
6                                    NA    NA    NA    NA                                               
7         Drawing_Dog_Natural.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         L                                     
8     Playdoh_Winky_Unnatural.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         A                                     
9      Drawing_Flower_Natural.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         L                                     
10   Playdoh_Turtle_Unnatural.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         A                                     
11  Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         L                                     
12      Drawing_House_Natural.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         L                                     
13   Playdoh_Flower_Unnatural.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         A                                     
14 Drawing_PalmTree_Unnatural.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         A                                     
15       Drawing_Boat_Natural.mp4    NA    NA    NA    NA         L                                     
   Playdoh_Butterfly_01 Playdoh_Flower_01 Playdoh_Snail_01 Playdoh_Tree_01 Playdoh_Turtle_01 Playdoh_Winky_01
1                                                                                                            
2                                                                                                            
3                                                                                                            
4                                                                                                            
5                                                                                                            
6                                                                                                            
7                                                                                                            
8                                                                                                    NAT_left
9                                                                                                            
10                                                                                  NAT_left                 
11            NAT_right                                                                                      
12                                                                                                           
13                               NAT_left                                                                    
14                                                                                                           
15                                                                                                           
   time.frame completed exp_subject_id group_name rec_session_id Screen_Height Screen_Width session_name
1          NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
2          NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
3          NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
4          NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
5          NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
6          NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
7          NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
8          NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
9          NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
10         NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
11         NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
12         NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
13         NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
14         NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
15         NA       yes         241482    group_1         261254           900         1440    session_1
   session_nr subj_counter_global time_delay_offset time_measure_std unlocked Window_Height Window_Width
1           1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
2           1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
3           1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
4           1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
5           1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
6           1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
7           1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
8           1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
9           1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
10          1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
11          1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
12          1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
13          1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
14          1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
15          1                  12           27.2 ms         150.1 ms     true           900         1440
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drop specific values from the data you can use -

```
library(dplyr)

values_to_remove <- c("Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4", 
                      "Playdoh_Butterfly_Unnatural.mp4")

result <- import %>% filter(!(filename_left %in% values_to_remove | 
                              filename_right %in% values_to_remove))
```

The same code can also be used in base R `subset` -

```
result <- subset(import, !(filename_left %in% values_to_remove | 
                           filename_right %in% values_to_remove))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely understand the question, but if these filenames are only located in these two columns, you can just take these values out after importing:

```
import <- read.csv("rawData/session_1_anon.csv")

import <- import[import$filename_right != "Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4",]
import <- import[import$filename_left != "Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4",]
import <- import[import$filename_right != "Playdoh_Butterfly_Unnatural.mp4",]
import <- import[import$filename_left != "Playdoh_Butterfly_Unnatural.mp4",]
```

Not very elegant, but should work

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
values_to_remove <- c("Playdoh_Butterfly_Natural.mp4", 
                      "Playdoh_Butterfly_Unnatural.mp4")
result <- import %>% slice(which(!(filename_left %in% values_to_remove | 
                              filename_right %in% values_to_remove)))
```